# Double selection with RAND() in php

Tags: php, mysql

Please I need help with this problem I'm facing. I'm building an examination system and I'm using the Rand() function to select questions from the "question" table. The user's answers are also saved in the "user_answer" table.

Now my problem is a question sometimes gets selected twice or thrice so I need a query that will check that if a question has already been answered in the "user_answer" table, it should reselect another question from the "question" table.

Comment: What code are you using now?

Comment: So, no code. Ok, well you have what may be a "magic" answer below; ask them. If that doesn't work, then guess what? Yeah, the operative word here is "guess" which is what your question revolves around.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot exclude with Rand() directly.

If you query from a database, you could add something like

```
select *
from question q
left join user_answer ua on ua.question_id = q.id
where ua.id is null
group by q.id
```

This will try to connect to an answer (ANY answer, you probably want to add some user selection into that), and only give back the questions where it FAILS (ua.id is null) to do so.

If you cannot do it by query and have it it all in some PHP array, what you could do is keep track of the available question ID's in an array. Each time you pick a question random, you remove that item (value!) from the array, and reindex the array (keeping the values, which are the question ID's, and ordering the keys from 0 to the number of questions - 1).

That way you can do a rand(0, count($questionIds)) again to pick the next one.

Another way would be to use a loop, and continue as long as the picked question is already in the used questions array.